# How do I control an object in processing via Arduino sketch?

Tags: arduino, processing

I have managed to connect the Arduino sketch to a Processing sketch, but I am stuck on how I get the Arduino to control an object in the processing.

Using a tilt sensor, the aim is that when the tilt sensor is tilted one way it will move the object in processing that way, and then when it is tilted the other way it will move the object the other way.

Can anyone help?

This is my code for Arduino:

```java
void setup() 
{
  // put your setup code here, to run once:
Serial.begin(9600);
}

void loop() 
{
  // put your main code here, to run repeatedly:
Serial.println("Hello, World!");

delay(100);

}
```

This is my code for Processing:

```java
import processing.serial.*;
Serial myPort;
String val;
PShape bike;

void setup()
{
String portName = Serial.list()[0];
myPort = new Serial(this, portName, 9600); 

size(800, 600);
bike = createShape(RECT, 0, 0, 200, 200);
bike.setFill(color(102, 204, 0));
bike.setStroke(false);

}

void draw()
{
  if ( myPort.available() > 0) 
  {  // If data is available,
  val = myPort.readStringUntil('\n');         // read it and store it in val
  } 
println(val); //print it out in the console

shape(bike, 0, 0);

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Break your problem down into smaller pieces.

Write a simple example sketch (in other words a [mcve]) that only does one thing: it simply reads in values from the Arduino and prints them to the console. It doesn't even really need to draw anything to the screen.

Write another [mcve] that just does one thing: it simply moves an object on screen. Notice that this should **not** involve your Arduino code at all. Try to make it as standalone as possible.

When you get both of these working completely separately, then you can think about combining them into one sketch. And if you get stuck, you can post that [mcve] along with a specific technical question.

Here's a sketch that moves an object based on the mouse position, just go get you started:

```java
float objectX = 0;

void setup() {
  size(500, 100);
}

void draw() {

  if (mouseX > objectX) {
    objectX ++;
  }

  background(0);
  ellipse(objectX, height/2, 25, 25);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

your arduino code looks that´s only hello world.
What I do to use arduino libs (sensors, actuators) using processing, is to split the tasks for 2 arduinos: one that uses the libs and send/recive data from the other arduino. This second arduino is loaded with the standard firmdata (firmware), that allows to comunicate easily and directly from processing sketch: http://playground.arduino.cc/Interfacing/Processing